# Is a std::string_view literal guaranteed to be null-terminated?

Tags: c++, string, c++17, standards, string-view

I know that a trivial `std::string_view` is not guaranteed to be null-terminated. However, I don't know if a `std::string_view` literal is guaranteed to be null-terminated.

For example:

```
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::literals;

int main()
{
    auto my_sv = "hello"sv;
}
```

**Does C++17 or later guarantee that `my_sv.data()` is null-terminated?**

**=== Below is updated ===**

All of below are from [n4820](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/raw/master/papers/n4820.pdf):

> 1. As per 5.13.5.14, a string literal is null-terminated.
> 2. As per 5.13.8, a user-defined-string-literal is composed of a string literal plus a custom suffix. Say, `"hello"sv`, `hello` is the string literal, `sv` is the suffix.
> 3. As per 5.13.8.5, `"hello"sv` is treated as a call of the form `operator "" sv(str, len);` as per 5.13.5.14, `str` is
>      null-terminated.
> 4. As per 21.4.2.1, `sv`'s `data()` must return `str`.

**Can they prove that `"hello"sv.data()` is guarantteed to be null-terminated by the C++ standard?**

Comment: On this site use the green checkmark on an answer to indicate "Solved"; absence of such a checkmark indicates "Unsolved". You should not write "solved" etc. in the title

Comment: `string_view` is a class. Classes aren't null-terminated.  It would improve the question to explain exactly what you are asking (perhaps give a code sample of usage of the string_view that demonstrates the case you are asking about)

Comment: @M.M Isn't it pretty clear what the OP is asking? Do you think that adding a few lines of code like [those](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nVC8KoQk6dJ4Yc9O) would be beneficial?

Comment: @M.M `sv[sv.size()]` is UB, `sv.data()[sv.size()]` isn't necessarily UB -- but should cause squeamishness. It's also not clear to me which one the OP is asking about.

Comment: @M.M So the question may be rephrased into something like as *"given `auto my_sv = "hello"sv;`, does C++17 or later guarantees that `my_sv.data()` is null-terminated?"*

Comment: @Barry Right, I don't see anything in the standard prohibiting that code either (although it's surely not any recommended style of course).

Comment: What I really mean is whether data() will return a null-terminated c-string.

Comment: @M.M: http://eel.is/c++draft/string.view.access#4

Comment: @Bob__ It could be that there is a null-terminator but it causes undefined behaviour to try and inspect the terminator;  it's not clear to me whether that scenario is described by "my_sv.data() is null-terminated", or not. A more concrete question might be to ask whether `sv.data()[sv.size()] == 0` is correct and guaranteed

Comment: Bah, nothing constrains the result of `data()` though so actually I don't think there's a huge amount of wiggle room here. Darn.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

So let's get the simple parts out of the way. No `string_view` is ever "NUL-terminated", in the sense that the object represents a sized range of characters. Even if you create a `string_view` from a NUL-terminated sequence of characters, the `string_view` *itself* is still not "NUL-terminated".

The question you're really asking is this: does the implementation have some leeway to make the statement `"some literal"sv` yield a `string_view` whose `data` member *does not* point into the NUL-terminated string literal represented by `"some literal"`? That is, is this:

```
string_view s = "some literal"sv;
```

permitted to behave in *any way* differently from this:

```
const char *lit = "some literal";
string_view s(lit, <number of chars in of lit>);
```

In the latter case, `s.data()` is guaranteed to be a pointer to the string literal, and thus you could treat that pointer as a pointer to a NUL-terminated string. You're asking if the former is just as valid.

Let's investigate. The [definition for the `operator""sv` overloads are stated to be](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/string.view.literals):

> ```
> constexpr string_view operator""sv(const char* str, size_t len) noexcept;
> ```
>
> Returns: `string_­view{str, len}`.

That is the standard specification for the behavior of this function: it returns a `string_view` which points into the memory supplied by `str`. Therefore, the implementation cannot allocate some hidden memory and use that or whatever; the returned `string_view::data` *is required* to return the same pointer as `str`.

Now, this brings us to a different question: is `str` *required* to be a NUL-terminated string? That is, is it legal for a compiler to sees that you are using the `sv` UDL implementation and therefore remove the NUL character from the array it was going to create for the string literal passed as `str`?

Let's look at [how UDLs for strings work](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.ext#5):

> If `L` is a user-defined-string-literal, let `str` be the **literal without its ud-suffix** and let `len` be the number of code units in `str` (i.e., its length **excluding the terminating null character**). The literal `L` is treated as a call of the form
>
> ```
> operator "" X(str, len)
> ```

Note the phrases I emphasized. We know the behavior of "the literal without its ud-suffix". And the second phrase makes specific mention of the expected NUL terminator for `str`. I'd say that's a pretty clear statement that `str` will be given a literal string. And that literal string will be built in accord with regular string literal rules in C++, and therefore will be NUL-terminated.

Given the above, I think it is safe to say that there is no wiggle room for the implementation here. The `string_view` returned by the UDL *must* point to the array defined by the string literal specified in the UDL, and like any other string literal, that array *will* be NUL-terminated.

That having been said, *please* review my first paragraph. You should not write any code which assumes that a `string_view` is NUL-terminated. I would call it a code smell even if the creator of the `string_view` and is consumer are right next to each other.